# Adding to an unordered list in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm adding list items to a jquery mobile project dynamically in script:

```
<ul id="list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
      <li data-icon="plus"><a href="#new-thingy" data-transition="slideup">Create new thingy</a></li>
</ul>
```

With the following JQuery code:

```
$("<li><a href='#foo'>foo</a></li>").prependTo("#home-events-list");
$("#list").trigger('refresh');
```

The list items are being added but they aren't 'enhanced'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

your ul has id `list` not `home-events-list`

Second:

You want

```
$('#list').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Bingo! The first was a simple typo in my question (sorry!). The second was my problem.

Comment: If you didn't know tis, you might also profit from visiting my faq http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html